# Mapping unit disk with slit at $[0,1)$ conformally onto unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}$ denote the unit disk in the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$. I want to find a conformal mapping of the slit disk $\mathbb{D}-[0, 1)$ onto $\mathbb{D}$.

Here's what I know so far:
The conformal mapping $$\phi(z)= e^{i \theta} \frac{z-a}{1- \bar{a}z}, |z|<1$$ with $a \in \mathbb{C},|a|<1, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi$ maps $\mathbb{D}$ onto $\mathbb{D}$. I'm also familiar with the standard mappings from the upper half plane onto the unit disk and vice versa. Since we are considering a slit disk to be mapped onto the unit disk, would that entail the composite of $\phi$ with an appropriate branch of the square root function? I'm still trying to come up with an explicit mapping of some sort, but haven't gotten very far yet. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Your "slit disc" should probably be denoted $\mathbb{D} - [0,1)$.

Comment: My advice would be to just look at a step at a time, and then compose the maps together later to see what your final function is.

A useful first step might be to consider the image of your set under a standard conformal map from D to H, then see where the slit gets mapped to, and see if you can map it to a useful place by applying a Mobius transform to D (of the form $\phi$ in your post) prior to applying the conformal map D->H.

Comment: Your idea of using a branch of the square root as a first step sounds right, and having done that ask yourself what the image of the slit disc looks like.

Comment: @Lee Mosher: Typo fixed.